# awk character class mystery

Tags: awk

I seem to be unable to use a character class for an **awk** regular expression, almost exactly as described [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Bracket-Expressions.html) :

```
user@host:~$ awk -W version
mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996, Copyright (C) Michael D. Brennan

compiled limits:
max NF             32767
sprintf buffer      2040
user@host:~$ echo "host.company.com has address 192.168.22.82" |awk '/^[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+ has address/ { print $4 }'
192.168.22.82
user@host:~$ echo "host.company.com has address 192.168.22.82" |awk '/^[[:alnum:].-]+ has address/ { print $4 }'
user@host:~$
```

Does anyone see why the second command fails to find the address field?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a bug in `mawk 1.3.3` and was reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mawk/+bug/69724). You can upgrade to `mawk 1.3.4` or use patch to fix the bug.

```
$ mawk -W version
mawk 1.3.4 20130219
Copyright 2013, Thomas E. Dickey
Copyright 1996, Michael D. Brennan

internal regex
compiled limits:
max NF             32767
sprintf buffer      2040

$ echo "host.company.com has address 192.168.22.82" | mawk '/^[[:alnum:].-]+ has address/ { print $4 }'
192.168.22.82
```

`mawk` uses extended regular expressions as with `egrep`, so it must support POSIX characters classes.

Answer (score 5):

The documentation that you're referring to is of the GNU version of `Awk`, but the version you've is [mawk](http://invisible-island.net/mawk/) (as shown by your first command) which is an `awk` variant that doesn't seem to support POSIX character classes like `[:alpha:]` or `[:alnum:]`.

Edit: As [mentioned by Gnouc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149064/11912), `mawk` does support POSIX character classes from version `1.3.4` onwards, so an update could fix your issue.

Comment: No, `mawk` suppport POSIX characters classes. See my answer.

Comment: In the [manual](http://invisible-island.net/mawk/manpage/mawk.txt) from the link you posted, it says it supports Posix 1003.2 (draft 11.3) and is based on the 1988 Aho, Kernighan and Weinberger awk book...

Comment: You're right. The links that I referred to for my answer were quite old during which there was no support for POSIX character classes.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding gawk vs. mawk POSIX classes, i can't speak for the other classes, but strangely enough, only mawk 1.3.4 seems to have it right when it comes to the class -

```
[[:graph:]]
```

I haven't tested more obsolete/obscure variants, but both gawk 5.1 and mawk2-beta, which align with each other in this particular class, are missing a quite a few printable characters in Korean Hangul and Chinese Han characters. doing something like

```
/[[:graph:]]|[\352\353\354]/
```

*mostly* does the trick, but still a few residuals out in \355 that don't have any discernible pattern allowing for writing a clean regex to account for the gap. I can only pray the gnu code maintainers find time for it, but also recognizing the reality that it's likely extremely low on anyone's priority list.